# Expected outcome in group capture?

Tags: java, regex, capture-group

```
String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
    String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
      System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
      System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
      System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3));
    }
```

output is

```
Found value: This order was placed for QT300
Found value: 0
Found value: ! OK?
```

Though i was expecting the output as

```
Found value: This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
Found value: 3000
Found value: This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
```

The reason for my expected output is

```
If pattern is  "(.*)"   output for m.group(1) is "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?"
If pattern is  "(\\d+)" output for m.group(1) is "3000"
```

I don't know when I mention pattern as `"(.*)(\\d+)(.*)"`; why I am not getting expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the first `(.*)` being too greedy and eat up as much as possible, while still allowing `(\d+)(.*)` to match the rest of the string.

Basically, the match goes like this. At the beginning, the first `.*` will gobble up the whole string:

```
This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
                                     ^
```

However, since we can't find a match for `\d+` here, we backtrack:

```
This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
                                    ^
This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
                                   ^
...

This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
                               ^
```

At this position, `\d+` can be matched, so we proceed:

```
This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
                                ^
```

and `.*` will match the rest of the string.

That's the explanation for the output you see.

---

You can fix this problem by making the first `(.*)` *lazy*:

```
(.*?)(\d+)(.*)
```

The search for match for `(.*?)` will begin with empty string, and as it backtracks, it will gradually increase the amount of characters it gobbles up:

```
This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
^
This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
 ^
...

This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
                            ^
```

At this point, `\d+` can be matched, and `.*` can also be matched, which finishes the matching attempt and the output will be as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

The `.*` is matching (and consuming) as much characters as it can before finding `\\d+`. When it gets to `\\d+`, only one number is enough for matching.

So, you need to make the `.*` lazy:

```
(.*?)(\\d+)(.*)
```

Well, if you want to go into the details, `.*` first matches the whole string, then backtracks  one character at a time so that the regex can also match `(\\d+)(.*)` which comes later on. Once it has backtracked to the last character here:

```
This order was placed for QT300
```

The rest of the regex (`(\\d+)(.*)`) is satisfied so the matching ends.