# group() in java.util.regex.Matcher?

Tags: java, regex

```
String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)";
while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
     }
```

Input:

```
This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
```

Output :

```
This order was placed for QT300
0
```

Why in the first line of output it doesnot include the third 0 i.e QT3000?
Why is the second line of output it doesnot print 3000?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969436/java-regex-capturing-groups), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675870/expected-outcome-in-group-capture) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075643/getting-groups-of-a-pattern) amongst others...

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `.*` which is greedy and leave just one `\d` for the group `\\d+`.Make it non greedy `.*?` and you will get what you want.

`.*` will match upto the last char and then start backtracking until it finds `\d`.So when it encouters `0` from `3000` while coming backwards it stops right there.

`.*?` will stop at the first instance of `\d` i.e `3`.So you will get `3000` in your second group.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `.*` is greedy which matches all the characters as much as possible. So `.*` matches all the chars upto the last and then it backtracks until it finds a digit since `\d+` was given in the regex. `\d+` matches one or more digits. So it won't backtrack to the next digit since the condition of matching atleast one digit was already done. Solution is, you need to make the `.*` as non-greedy `"(.*?)(\\d+)"`.

Comment: You don't provide the solution, you just describe the cause.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i saw many why's in his question..

Comment: Yes, but providing the explanation **and** the solution would be better.

Comment: But in the doc X* and X*? both have the meaning 0 or more times.

Comment: yep, it matches zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

Vks and Raj have explained your question in very detail, but without examples.
So I found an article on Oracle which provides  a clear explanation,  accompanying many examples. Hope it could help
[Pattern quantifier explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)